# How can I open a page and change the active class of an element based on an id?

Tags: jquery, html

Here's my issue:

My client has a website: http://d2p.wisc.edu

We want to create links which open a new page and then pull open a particular tab on that page.

```
Example:
<a href="https://d2p.wisc.edu/entrepreneur-lean-start-ups/">How mentors are involved</a>
```

Naturally this anchor tag just opens the page we're trying to lead the visitor to. But, we still want to open the 'Mentor' tab on the page.

My first inclination was to add the tab id to url

```
Example:
<a href="https://d2p.wisc.edu/entrepreneur-lean-start-ups/#1437586970870-a9895403-19ee">How mentors are invlolved</a>
```

Unfortuntatly the way the elements are set up, they use a class assignment and when a seperate tab is clicked they are either shown or displayed based on a ".vc_active" class. So this method currently just pulls the viewport down to a hidden element on the page.

In an attempt to resolve this issue, we're working on writing a script which matches the URL to the panel id and moves the ".vc_active" to the matching element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
   if(location.hash) {
       var panelRef = (window.location.hash.substring(1));  
       var aRef = (window.location.hash);  
       var panelID = jQuery(".vc_tta-panel").attr("id");
       var aHref = jQuery(".vc_tta-tab a").attr("href");
       console.log(panelRef);
       console.log(aRef);
       console.log(panelID);
       console.log(aHref);
       if( panelID == panelRef ) {
               jQuery(".vc_tta-tab").removeClass("vc_active");
               jQuery(".vc_tta-panel").removeClass("vc_active");
               jQuery(a).attr("href", "aRef").parent(".vc_tta-tab").addClass("vc_active");
               console.log("It Works!");
       }
    };     
});
```

The issue that we seem to be having is that we're unsure of how to look at all of the id's of all the panels and select the one that we want.

Am I approaching this the right way or, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do something whereby on page load you store the URL, split that out and do a match to an if else statement.

if the id matches: "#1437586970870-a9895403-19ee" then add a class of ".vc_active" to the li that contains "mentor".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something a little more simple such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if(location.hash) {
        var panelRef = (window.location.hash.substring(1));  
        var aRef = (window.location.hash);  
        console.log(panelRef);
        console.log(aRef);
        jQuery("a[href='" + aRef + "']").parent(".vc_tta-tab").siblings(".vc_tta-tab").removeClass("vc_active");
        jQuery("#" + panelRef).siblings(".vc_tta-panel").removeClass("vc_active");
        jQuery("a[href='" + aRef + "']").parent(".vc_tta-tab").addClass("vc_active");
        jQuery("#" + panelRef).addClass("vc_active");
        console.log("It Works!");
     };     
});
</script>
```

Let me know what you think!

Comment: The 2 issues that present themselves with this are that the .vc_active gets removed from all other elements on the page, and the viewport is still pushed down below the element.

Comment: Hey I edited my answer let me know if that works better. Still working on a solution for the view-port issue.